# Permutation equivalence

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Given the following permutation:
$$ψ=\begin{pmatrix}1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ 7\\ 3\ 6\ 1\ 7\ 2\ 5\ 4\end{pmatrix}$$
I have to find the period and if $$ψ^{74} = ψ^{-5}$$
I managed to find the period (which is 6) but I can't figure out how to prove the equivalence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\psi^{74}=\psi^{-5}\iff\psi^{79}=1.$$
Now since the period of $\psi$ is $6$, $\psi^n=\psi^{n\bmod 6}$.

Comment: Thank you, so since the module 6 of 79 is still 1, the equivalence is proven right, isn't it?

Comment: On the contrary: $\psi^{79}=\psi$, not $1$.

Comment: Okay I understood now, thank you again

Comment: You're  welcome!